# Do photons emitted by grow lights really lose energy over the distance of a few feet?

Tags: visible-light

I have watched videos where they test grow lights PAR(Photosynthetically active radiation) values at different distances.  It seems to me that at the speed light is moving, a foot or two should not make a difference.  Just wondering why light can lose so much energy over such a short distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some good answers, loss of light intensity follows the inverse square law from dispersion. what this does essentially is, if a pot plant were on a tall stool, directly under the light, it would catch most of the light. Several feet below it there would be shadows of the leaves on the floor, and not much light on the floor. Now remove the stool and set the pot plant on the floor, the leaves shadow's will be much smaller, and directly under the plant, and much of the floor will be lit up with wasted light. All of the individual photons light up something in both cases, but the plant gets more of them when it is closer. Hope this can give you a more visual understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Photons do not lose energy by traveling through air (not *exactly* true, but close enough for the OP's question).  Also, negligible absorption occurs when visible light travels through air, so the number of photons does not change.  However, as you get farther from the source, the photons are spread out further, so the number passing though a unit area gets smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the videos it is hard to be sure, but I assume the loss of energy is caused by dispersion, ie it is simply the light fanning out over a bigger area and thus becoming less intense in any one spot.

Answer (score -2):

Constant energy ( of emitted light) have to occupy growing volume of surrounding space. Volume grows very fast: at least as d^3 even in empty space.

Where there is anything material inside, additional interactions have to be present further dissipating energy.

It's quite general formula for such energy density loss, which follow from wave equation ( in a regimes where waves are good for description of electromagnetic field propagation), and it is nearly independent of the kind of field we talking about.

Comment: I can't think of any application that cares about the *volume* of space that light occupies. It's more typical to care about the amount of light falling on a *surface*, which grows as $d^2$ (still fast, but not as fast as volume).